# Prove that $\vert x-2y\vert=A^2$

Tags: number-theory

$$
(x-2y)(2y-1)\vert x^2-4y+1
$$
Prove that
$$
\vert x-2y\vert = A^2
$$

|x-2y|=A^2 means |x-2y|=perfect square

I could not find ideas for problem

Comment: What is $A{{}}$?

Comment: |x-2y|=perfect square

Answer (score 0):

We start from

$$(x-2y)(2y-1) \mid x^2 - 4 y + 1$$

and substitute $x' = x - 2 y$. This gives

$$x' (2 y -1) n = (x' + 2y)^2 - 4y + 1 $$

for a certain integer $n$.

Simplified and rearranged we have

$$(*) \quad x' (2 y - 1) n = x' (x' + 4 y) + (2 y - 1)^2$$

This proves $x' \mid (2y -1)^2$.

Now let $p$ be a prime with $p^m \mid 2 y -1$ and $m$ maximal with this property. Then $p \neq 2$. Now assume $p \mid x'$. Then $p \nmid (x' + 2 (2 y - 1) + 2)$, so $p \nmid (x' + 4y)$.

From $(*)$ we conclude $p^m \mid x'(x' + 4y)$ and by $p \nmid (x' + 4y)$ we have $p^m \mid x'$. So again from $(*)$ this means $p^{2m} \mid x'(x' + 4 y)$ and again $p^{2m} \mid x'$. From $x' \mid (2 y - 1)^2$ we conclude that $p^{2m}$ is the exact power of $p$ appearing in $x'$ which concludes the proof.